# Cricket puzzler

Tags: cricket, officiating

I've followed cricket for decades in the UK, and I can now watch it on ESPN here in the US. The sound technology and microphones pick up everything on the pitch.

I am puzzled by a shout heard after the ball is bowled. *Someone* shouts "play on!" but I can't figure out who.

I'm guessing it's an umpire letting the players know it's a valid ball. But who of the two umpires is calling and why doesn't it seem to be called for every ball?

Comment: Edits were made to correct your terminology, which I see you have changed back to the incorrect form. "Fair ball" is not a phrase used in cricket. The correct phrase for a legitimate delivery leading to play is "ball" or "valid ball" (and corresponding, an illegitimate delivery is "no ball").

Comment: You are probably hearing the non-striking batsman call "*run on*".  When the ball goes behind the striking batsman, it is down to the non-striker to call a run.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess here is that you're confused by something. Certainly neither of the umpires (note there are only two on the field) would ever make any indication that a ball is a valid delivery - they call no balls and wides, but make no indication for a fair delivery.

Without seeing the coverage it's hard to say any more, but if you *forced* me to guess, it would be one of the batsmen saying "no run" (which sort of vaguely rhymes with "play on"), a standard indication to their partner that they should *not* attempt to take a run.